# Cannot make push/pull to two different github accounts work

Tags: github, ssh

I have two GItHub accounts on one computer - one for work and one for my own projects. Despite reading a virtual pile of guides setting up a working system, I have so far failed - the work
account pushes-pulls correctly but my own account either fails (ERROR: repository not found) or asks for credentials (which fails because the method is disabled).

So far I have the following:

Working ssh keys for both accounts
(tested with `ssh -T git@github.com-Worker` and `git@github.com-HobbyHorse`)
A config file in .ssh directory:

```
#Worker account
Host github.com-Worker
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_worker

#HobbyHorse account
Host github.com-HobbyHorse
    HostName github.com
    User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_hobby
```

Pushing and pulling on the work account succeeds (and I am able to work),
but fails on my own account. Somehow I am unable to tell git to use the
HobbyHorse key for logging in.

`git config --local --get user.name`
correctly gives 'HobbyHorse

`git remote add  origin git@github.com:HobbyHorse/HobbyProject.git git push --set-upstream origin master`

gives the error:
`ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`
I am sure I've checked for typos and such. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up specific hostnames in `~/.ssh/config` but you didn't use them. It's about the same as if you put a friend's name and new phone number in your address book, and then kept texting or calling the old number.

For the existing repo you mentioned, `git remote set-url origin github.com-HobbyHorse:HobbyHorse/HobbyProject.git` should fix it.

For new repos, `git clone github.com-HobbyHorse:owner/repo` will clone with your "HobbyHorse credentials", and `git clone github.com-Worker:owner/repo` will clone with your "worker" credentials.